# How to differentiate capture groups with the same format in Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm going through several log entires in one log file and each of them contain this line:

```
Completed in 0.00023 (4328 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00010 (45%) | DB: 0.00000 (0%)
```

My capture groups are:

```
0.00023 (4328 reqs/sec)
0.00010 (45%)
0.00000 (0%)
```

I need to parse each log entry and store the parsed values inside a database.

Example:

```
       cycle_time        |  render-time   |  active_record 
                         |                | 
 0.00023 (4328 reqs/sec) |  0.00010 (45%) |     0.00000 (0%)
                         |                |
```

I'm using regex to parse them but my problem is I can't differentiate the values from each other since they almost have the same format. I currently use this regex expression:

```
\d\.\d{5}\s\(\d{1,2}\%\)
```

However, it only captures the values of render_time and active_record and it can't even differentiate between the two. Any ideas?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Try [`Completed in\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\([^)]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/dx8B3k/1). The required items are present in Groups 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @Gurman I'm working on RoR. Your expression actually returned a more accurate result, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
((?<=Completed in ).+?(?= \|)).*((?<=Rendering: ).+?(?= \|)).*((?<=DB: ).*)$
```

Which will give you 3 groups that you can then store separately into your database:

```
 1. 0.00023 (4328 reqs/sec)
 2. 0.00010 (45%)
 3. 0.00000 (0%)
```